# vscode didn't go into the breakpoint during remote debugging python

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I was using VScode's remote debugging for python files. The remote debugging function works well for a few days, suddenly it couldn't go into the breakpoint and keep the following state for a long time:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5ux1.png)
through the CALL STACK sidebar, we can see
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3EE8.png)

seems subprocess kept running all the time.
Could anyone tell me what happened to vscode? How could I fix this problem?

Comment: sorry that I forget to say, vscode 1.57.1 and  python 3 are used.

Comment: Could you provide a sample code with the breakpoint location to reproduce your error?

Comment: @ymentha14, could you tell me what the meaning is for the rightmost green sign in the first picture?

Answer (score 0):

@ymentha14
thanks a lot for your comments. I found the reason for the problem. There's a bug in writing of the code, thus vscode went into the subprocess and kept recurrent callback, which seems not to make it go into breakpoint.